# Compare two List[CustomObject] in Scala

Tags: scala

Let's say that I have 2 lists :

```
val list1:List[CustomObject] = List(obj1, obj2, obj3)
val list2:List[CustomObject] = List(obj4, obj5, obj6)
```

I was wondering if there is a kind of approach in Scala that takes these 2 lists and compares if `obj.name` from the first list occures in the second list.

This can be done using 2 inner loops and a flag.
However, I was wondering if there is something in Scala that can do that.

Comment: It is not very clear exactly what you want. Could you provide an example of input and expected output?

Comment: Imagine we have a Class called Car that has 2 attributes :
carName & CarColor

Now we have 2 lists :
list1=List(carObj1,carObj2,carObj3)
list2=List(carObj4,carObj5,carObj6)

Let's assume that carObj3.name==carObj4.name

The result I expect :
result:List[Car]=List[carObj1,carObj2,carObj5,carObj6]

Comment: I have figured an approach out : val result=
for(z<-list2 if !list1.contains(z))
yield z

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the attribute you want to use to compare is ordered, then this works:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet
val set1 = SortedSet(list1: _*)(Ordering by (_.name))
val set2 = SortedSet(list2: _*)(Ordering by (_.name))

val result = set1 &~ set2 union set2 &~ set1
val result2 = set1 | set2 diff set1 & set2 // also works
```

Now, if that is not possible, this works:

```
for {
  x <- list1 ++ list2 // you want elements from both, right?
  if list1.forall(_.name != x.name) || list2.forall(_.name != x.name)
} yield x
```

Highly inefficient. To make it efficient, use a `Map`:

```
def carName = (x: Car) => x.name -> x
val map1 = (list1 map carName).toMap
val map2 = (list2 map carName).toMap
for {
  x <- list1 ++ list2 // you want elements from both, right?
  if map1(x).isEmpty || map2(x).isEmpty
} yield x
```

Answer (score 2):

Something similar to this should work

```
list1.exists(a => list2.exists( b => a.name == b.name))
```

Comment: Actually I have smth like that : 

    val list1=List(1,2,3,4,5)
    val list2=List(5,6,7,8)
    
    
    val result=
    list1.map(x=>{
    if((list2.exists(l=>l==x))==false)
    x
    })

The result is 

    result: List[AnyVal] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, ())

How could I just return List[Int]=List(1,2,3,4)

I believe that the solution for my issue is into Folding .. um still reading about it .

Answer (score 1):

The follwoing works fine with me :

```
 val comparisonResultList: List[Car] =
      for (l1 <- list1 if list2.filter(_.referenceName==l1.referenceName)==Nil)
      yield l1
```

Thanks all for ur support.